# Is there a go function to check quantity of returned rows from sql queryContext?

Tags: sql, go

The `sql/database` pkg is being used to find the name of a pond based on the pond's id.

Is there an alternative way to handle if there were no results? Perhaps something similar to `RowsAffected`?

```golang
    query := ` SELECT pondName FROM ` + constant.Tables.Pond.Locations + ` WHERE pondID=?`
    rows, err := db.QueryContext(ctx, query, 9)
    if err != nil {
       //handled
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    for rows.Next() {
        var ID string
        err = rows.Scan(
            &ID,
        )
        //appended
    }

    if len(appendedLocations) == 0 {
        //handled
    }
```

I'm purposefully passing down `9` because that `ID` doesn't exist on the DB. It's returning the err as `nil`. When my other endpoints reach this helper, it's being returned as `null`.

Comment: A query with no results is not an error. If number of rows you processed is zero after the for loop, you can return an error.

Comment: Yeah what I meant was, is there another way to check to see if the returned rows is zero, other than how I have it now

Comment: `Rows` interface doesn't give you more.

Comment: http://go-database-sql.org/errors.html and https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#pkg-variables